# how to change text in richtextbox in textchanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the text (to bold, subscript, etc...) of my RichTextBox as the user types, so here is my code:

```
private void FunctionRTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (IsEditing) return;
        IsEditing = true;
        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        //
        //populating 'paragraph'
        //
        flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        //using (FunctionRTB.DeclareChangeBlock()) {
            //FunctionRTB.BeginChange(); // tried this
            FunctionRTB.Document = flowDocument;
            //FunctionRTB.EndChange(); // with this, didnt work.
        //}
        IsEditing = false;
    }
```

But a getting:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set the Document property inside the scope of DeclareChangeBlock or BeginChange/EndChange calls.'
```

in:

```
FunctionRTB.Document = flowDocument;
```

I tried to use `DeclareChangeBlock()` and `BeginChange()/EndChange()`. But none worked.

Suggestions and links are welcome.

Comment: you need to use PreviewTextChanged Event if you want to change it or you will create a stack overflow as every time you change it it will call itself again

Comment: @DenisSchaf He prevented that with the `IsEditing` (flag?). As long as a `TextChangedEvent` is processing, all other Event-Calls will be omitted due the `if (IsEditing) return;`

Comment: @DenisSchaf I check for that event. And it doesn't exist in the richtextbox events.